# Possible to pass html element in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hi I'm wondering if it's possible to pass an html element, for example a div, as data in an ajax call. To give some more insight, I am trying to take that html element and create a new html file containing that element in another html file. Any thoughts?

Comment: You might take the innerHTML and send it as a POST field.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can send the html content.

```
var htmlContent = $("#divIdyouwanttosend").html();
$.ajax({
    url : "URL",
    data : { "htmlContent" : htmlContent },
    type : "POST"
});
```

It will send you the HTML content.

If you are planning to send the HTML code itself, then use

```
var htmlContent = $("#divIdyouwanttosend").outerHTML();
```

In terms of javascript:

```
var htmlContent = document.getElementById("divId").outerHTML
```

Comment: Neat! Would this also work for a canvas? So, if I had a canvas with something drawn on it, would the sent content still be meaningful or would it just be an html canvas tag that doesn't preserve whatever was drawn on it?

Comment: It would send only the canvas tag and it won't preserve the drawn content

Comment: Is it possible to preserve the drawn content?